# record combination with similar index

Tags: python, matrix, addition

I have a table that has year and a value. I want to combine all the same years, adding the value associated with each in python.

```
Input:
    year  value
    1999   1
    2000   0
    1999   2
    2000   3.56

Output:
    year  value
    1999   3
    2000   3.56
```

Here is the sorry piece I have been working on. I just want the names to be on the same figure with the correct x-values (as in input of the function).

```
> import pandas
import pylab
import matplotlib
from pandas import *
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import *

names = read_csv(r'C:\Users\joe\Documents\Python\baby-names2.csv')

name1=names[names['name']=='Joseph']
name2=names[names['name']=='Nancy']


name1 = name1.ix[0:,['year', 'prop']]
name2 = name2.ix[0:,['year', 'prop']]

name1 = name1.groupby(['year']).sum()
name2 = name2.groupby(['year']).sum()


import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print ( name1[:,1])

#plt.scatter(name1[:,0],name1[:,1])
#plt.plot(name2['year'],name2['prop'], color='Green')
#plt.plot(name2, color='Blue')

#plt.show()
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) . If you do decide to use pandas, you'd do `df.groupby('year').sum()`.

Comment: what is the table? text file? csv? dict? list?

Comment: how is this table represented? Is it in a file? What is the delimiter?

Comment: `I am still learning.` -- We all (most of us?) are.  Is that an excuse not to try?

Comment: @devnull I have been trying, for an eternity, thanks for the faith!

Comment: It would be better to provide all the information in your question when you initially ask it.

Comment: @PyNEwbie I will from now on. I dont want people to think I am on here just leeching all the help I can get. I was trying to simplify my question earlier. sorry if that did not help.